# How do I get data from a promise object and put it into an HTML list using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, jsx

I'm using a promise to get a list of topics from AWS SNS, and having it log to the console. That's working great, but what I'm having an issue figuring out is how to get that information and put it into a list so I can show it on a webpage.

Here's the code for listing the topics into the console:

```
    import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.accessKeyId = "My_Key";
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "My_Secret_Key";
    // Set region
    AWS.config.update({ region: 'My_Region' });
    // Create promise and SNS service object
    const ListTopicsPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31' 
    }).listTopics({}).promise();
    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states

    ListTopicsPromise.then(
        function (data) {
           console.log(data.Topics);
        }).catch(
    function (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
```

I'm thinking that I need to make this into a function somehow, so I can get it to return a div with a list within it. I'm just unsure how to do that. Is there any more info you need, or any advice you have? Thank you for taking the time to look into this while I keep trying to figure it out!

Edit: I've snipped out an image of what I get from my console log in case this will help at all.

[Console Topic List Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVoi6.png)
Here's the code from App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';
import ListTopicsPromise from './aws/listTopics';

AWS.config.update({
    region: awsmobile.aws_cognito_region,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: awsmobile.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id
    })
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    topics: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Fetch data, then using 'setState' set it to topics.
    ListTopicsPromise.then(
      data =>
      this.setState({ topics: data.Topics})
    ).catch(
      err => {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          {
            this.state.topics.map( topic =>
            <div>
              <p>Topic ID: {topic.id}</p>
              <p>Topic Title: {topic.title}</p>
            </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The component is the default component that comes when you install a react app using npx create-react-app my-app.

Comment: It depends on what format your data is being returned in but essentially, your best bet would be to put that data in your state when it's returned: `this.setState({ topics: data.Topics })` and then in your `render` function, assuming it's an array, you could map over it: `this.state.topics.map(topic => (<li>topic.name - topic.description</li>))`

Comment: I see just a `TopicArn` property in the array items.  Is that all?

Comment: Yep, that's the only property that gets returned from AWS when I call it. Each one has proto objects, but nothing else.

Comment: I don't know what is supposed to get back but I can't help for AWS part. If this data is what you want then you can use it like `topic.TopicArn`.

Comment: Ahha, I tried to do that as a fix but I just made a typo. Thank you for all of your help, dev. This solved everything.

Comment: You are welcome. Ok, let me update my answer so you can accept if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a proper lifecycle method to do async operations like you do here. After getting data we set this data to a proper state property. This is where we use `state`. `componentDidMount` is a suitable lifecycle method, so:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topics: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch data, then using `setState` set it to topics.
    ListTopicsPromise.then(
      data => 
        this.setState({ topics: data.Topics})
      ).catch(
        err => {
          console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      // map the data from state, then render it to the DOM.
      {
        this.state.topics.map( topic =>
          <div>
            <p>Topit Arn: {topic.TopicArn}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Notes:** You can set up AWS thingy in another file and can export `ListTopicsPromise`. I didn't use this part from your code. Also, I've used an arrow function in the `.then` callback since we are using `this` context there.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, devserkan! I think this is definitely on the right track; but now I'm getting a warning. "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." The console still lists my topics the page doesn't list anything except for:
Topic ID:
Topic Title:
I changed the names, since those were exactly the same. I did notice that it does list both of those for each item in the object, but it does not list them.

Comment: You are welcome. The warning is not so important, fixing it very easy. But if you see empty elements than this means you can't set your state properly. Please update your question and add your component. So we can look at what is the problem.

Comment: Alright, I edited it and added some more information. I'm using npx create-react-app, and didn't edit my component in any way from that. If you'd still like to see it, I can find it and post it.